# Is it possible to add an icon to the Windows System Image List?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

I display objects, some of which are files and folders in `TTreeView`, `TListView` and a few other custom controls.

When a folder is selected, I display its contents (files and folders) in `TListView`and I use the Windows System Image List to assign an icon.  I call `SHGetFileInfoW` to obtain an icon index.  `SHGetFileInfoW` is also used to obtain the System Image List Handle:

```
SHFILEINFOW info ;
DWORD Flags = (SHGFI_SMALLICON | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX) // for instance 

ImageList->Handle = SHGetFileInfoW( L"",
                                    0,
                                    &info,
                                    sizeof(SHFILEINFOW),
                                    Flags 
                                    ) ;
```

[image]

My program also keeps its own `ImageList` with icons, since it displays more than just files and folders.  In `TreeView` for instance a combination of 'other objects' and folder objects will be shown:

[image]

To keep folder icons consistent (same) between `TreeView` and `ListView` on different versions of the Windows OS, I copy the Windows System folder icon to my own `ImageList` during program start.
This way both `TreeView` and `ListView` use the same folder icon, and the icon is that of the OS the software is running on.

This has worked well for many years across many OS, from Win2K to W11. However I'd like to try the reverse approach now **IF** at all possible.  I'd like to use my own folder icon in both `ListView` and `TreeView`.  For `TreeView` this is not a problem, but for `ListView` it is an issue in every situation where files and folders are displayed together, since I use the Windows System Image List to display the file icons and hence also folder icons.

I can think of a workaround where I create the needed registry entries to register a very unique file extension that is associated with a folder icon in my executable.  I could then use that for folders.  But it's a workaround that may not always work perfectly if Windows doesn't refresh immediately etc.

So, the question, is it at all possible to add an icon to the System Image List during program execution ?  Is there a Windows API call that does this ?  If so I could use that Index then to display folder icons in `ListView`.

Comment: Touching anything labeled "system" sounds like a bad idea. Can you copy images from the system list into your one as needed?

Comment: I hear you.  But it's worth asking others.  I couldn't find it documented, so that says something probably.  Looking into my code I don't copy the folder icon from the System Icon List into my own ImageList, rather from system dlls but yes I believe it's possible using the same logic.  TIcon *Icon = new TIcon() ; Icon->Handle =.. ; ImageList->AddIcon(Icon) ;

Comment: You should not add custom icons to a system ImageList, only the Shell should do that. I would probably just forgo assigning the system ImageList directly to the ListView, and instead simply owner-draw the ListView items. If a list item represents a normal file/folder, draw it using an icon from the system ImageList. If a list item represents a custom object, draw it using my own icon as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

First off, in Windows NT based systems, the system image list is per-process and is not a full copy of the real list. In Windows 95 it really was global. This means the design never intended for people to add extra HICONs on their own directly into the list.

While it is called the system image list, the only thing it stores are file type icons and the shell extension overlays, it is not a general icon list.

There are two ways to add icons to the list:

- The common way is to use one of the shell functions (like `SHGetFileInfo`) to ask for information about a file path or extension.
- The other way is to call `Shell_GetCachedImageIndex`. This function used to be undocumented and was only documented because of the DOJ trial.

My suggestion: Use your own custom imagelist with your custom images. In slot 0 place an empty icon that you draw on top of with [custom draw](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/79/neat-stuff-to-do-in-list-controls-using-custom-dra) (not owner-draw).

Comment: Since it is a copy, how safe is it to use ImageList_Add() for instance, to add an icon ?  Or can Windows/Shell operations outside my program still change the process ImageList and basically undo my addition (should it work) ?  I'm not sure what you mean with your suggestion ?

Comment: It might even block it, I don't know. If you add your own icon directly you might run into collisions with the index, not sure, I have never tried it.